# Subversion update failed

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, devops, smartsvn

I've a Jenkins pipeline. When build is run, I can see `ERROR: Subversion update failed` error on console logs. I searched for this on google but could not get exact cause of this error.

Can someone please help me to understand what could be wrong here or point me to document link?

Note: I'm very new to svn.

Answer (score 1):

Which subversion plugin version you are using?
Java version?
Any more Logs on the stack trace?
Have you tried clearing the workspace, restart Jenkins and try again?